# Replicating Python functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, python-3.x

I've recently switched from `C` to OOP languages - `C++` and `Python 3.4`

I noticed that there are quite-a-lot things about `Python` that `C++` can't beat
one of them being the ease of calling functions.

So i've decided to somehow implement the python-way of making function calls in C++, using the STL.

I started off with the 'string' class.

In Python, i can do this:

```
str="hello world   "
str.strip().split()
```

and that would first, strip-off the trailing whitespaces at the end of the string and then split the string in 2 halves at at the whitespace

now that's **NEAT**
and i'd love to be able to call functions this way, ie, `object.func1().func2().func3()` and so on

as i have absolutely no idea about the stl class 'string', i started off with my own made class 'MYstring'

```
class MYstring
{
    string str;
public:
    //constructor
    MYstring(string str)
    {   setter(str);    }

    //setter function
    MYstring& setter( string str )
    {   this->str=str;
        return *this;
    }

    //getter_str function
    string getter_str()
    {   return str;
    }

    unsigned int getter_size()
    {   return str.size();
    }

    //modifier function(s)
    MYstring& split(char x='\0')
    {   string temp="";
        for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
        {   if(this->str[i-1] == x)
                break;
            temp += str[i];
        }
        this->str=temp;
        return *this;
    }

    MYstring& strip()
    {
        for(int i=this->str.size() - 1; i>=0; i--)
        {   if(this->str[i] == ' ')
                this->str.erase(i);
            else if(isalnum(this->str[i]))
                break;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

To test the class and its member functions, i used the following `main()`

```
int main()
{   //take a user-defined string-type input
    string input;
    cout<<"Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin,input);

    // create an object of class 'MYstring'
    // and initialise it with the input given by the user
    MYstring obj(input);

    //take the character at which the string must be split
    cout<<"\nEnter character to split the string at: ";
    char x;
    cin>>x;

    //display original input
    cout<<"\n\nThe user entered: "<<obj.getter_str();
    cout<<"\nSize = "<<obj.getter_size();

    obj.strip().split(x);//  <--- python style function call
    cout<<"\n\nAfter STRIP and SPLIT: "<<obj.getter_str();
    cout<<"\nSize = "<<obj.getter_size();

    return 0;
}
```

**And It Works**

So, finally here's my question:

How can I create and use the same `split` and `strip` functions for the `C++ STL string class`?
Is it possible to use our own created methods with the STL?

Every suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the class std::string and use the extended class. So your class will have all the functionality of the STL string plus you additional methods.

```
class mystring: public std::string {
   ...
};
```

Comment: @JBL just don't use virtual functions... the compiler will warn you if you do.

Comment: If you don't add additional attributes how can you have slicing?

Comment: @JBL But who creates `strings` with `new` anyway? This is not such a big deal. But I don't think it has any advangates over writing functions to operate on `string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience and on the topics covered in the link that starrify posts in the comments, I would not subclass the STL classes but instead create your own class as you've done.

But also, in addition to your std::string copy constructor you might add a typecast-to-std::string operator overload, so it's easy to have code convert to and from your object and std::string when working with libraries that take std::string.

Comment: so then, what's a good-enough workaround to prevent from happening what you just pointed?